# Citrix Receiver - mouse with a strange black box

Tags: citrix

When I logged in my work environment from Citrix Receiver in Windows it works normally. When I tried the same in Ubuntu it works but there is a black box about double size of mouse pointer. It does work but it seems too strange. Is there some specific configuration that I could look at?

Answer (score 3):

I was having this exact same problem. Apparently its to do with 'alpha blending' on the mouse pointer shadow (see here http://citrixblogger.org/2008/02/07/cursor-shadowing-turn-it-off/)

The following fix worked for me:

1) Log into citrix session
2) On the remote machine youre logged into go to:
3) Control Panel > Mouse > Pointers
4) Under Scheme select None
5) Hit apply

Hope this works for you.